# Trim numbers to n digits digits in a data frame

Tags: dataframe, select, trim, truncate, digits

```
> head(Conversion_tbl)
       X.Product.Code BEC.Product.Code
1          10121               41
2          10129              111
3          10130               41
4          10190              111
5          10221               41
6          10229              111

> tail(Conversion_tbl)
       X.Product.Code BEC.Product.Code
5381         970200               61
5382         970300               61
5383         970400               61
5384         970500               61
5385         970600               61
5386         999999                7
```

I have this df, I need to:

1) transform 2nd variable numbers to one digit, keeping only their first one (61 -> 6)

2) keep only first 2 digits in 1st variable (ex. 970200  -> 97). **Note** that first 561 observations are one digits shorter than others, hence I need only their first digit, preceded by a "0" (ex. 10121 -> 01,  84022 -> 08)

desired output:

```
      X.Product.Code BEC.Product.Code
1          01              4
5381       97              6
```

Comment: Please include the exact expected output here, along with an explanation.

Comment: like this ? I used first observations of tail and head